# Odd polynominal

Tags: polynomials, transformation

Let's define an odd polynominal be a polynominal which has odd degree, and ALL of its terms have odd exponential (except the constant), for example: $x^5+x^3+1$, or $x^7+2x^5+3x^3+4x+5$.

We all know that for every cubic polynominal $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d $, there always exists a linear transformation $t=t(x)$, such that it transforms the cubic to an odd polynominal $t^3+pt+q $ of degree 3

My question is, for every polynominal of odd degree $n$ , does there always exist a linear transformation $t=t(x)$ such that it transforms this polynominal to an odd polynominal of the same degree ?

A similar definition and question for an even polynominal: for every polynominal of even degree $n$ , does there always exist a linear transformation $t=t(x)$ such that it transforms this polynominal to an even polynominal of the same degree ?

Comment: Are the transformations $t$ general affine transformations, or just translations? (Note that translations are not linear in the sense of linear maps.)

Comment: Even if general affine transformations are allowed, that only gives you two parameters of freedom, whereas for "odd polynomials" of degree $> 5$ we're solving at least $3$ equations (i.e., substituting a general affine transformation and setting the even coefficients to zero), so for those degrees we should expect no solutions for a generic polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a counter example:
Take the polynomial $x^{5}+x^{2}+1 $ suppose that you have $a\neq0,b $ such that $P\left(at+b\right) $ is odd, then $5a^{4}b=0$ and, $a^{2}+\binom{5}{2}a^{2}b^{3}=0 $ a contradiction.

Comment: Interesting (and simple) counter example ! But why does it happen for degree > 3 ? Is there any relation with solvability of over-3-degree equation ?